# chrome focus select keyup

Tags: javascript, events

html:

```
<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

jquery:

```
$('select').on('keyup', function(){
   alert('hello'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PsVU7/

Chrome: then list is closed, not working keyup event  (only opens options). How to catch this event?

I need onkeyup event: if user press enter key, then application save select value, but I cannot catch keyup if list not opened. In FireFox works fine.

Comment: During selecting box you need to use `change` event despite of `keyup`

Comment: The keyup works fine in Chrome. Are you trying to say that you need to catch and save the value on enter but perhaps there is no focus on the list and you need that (according to the question title it has someting to do with the focus) ? Or you've changed the list with keyup/down and because of the alert you lost focus on the select and enter no longer works ?

Comment: try a console.log instead of alert and see if it works with enter after you use up and down keys to select your option

Comment: Same situation. Chrome, open http://jsfiddle.net/PsVU7/1/ , press on select with mouse, press enter (it works), press enter now on closed list (isnt work, only opens list).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('select').change(function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: I need keyup event to catch <enter> keyup